# Windows 8 won't start explorer on other accounts

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

I'm using Windows 8 for a long time, but some days ago something weird happened. I'm able to log in and use computer like before, but other accounts cannot log in and it stops at the black screen.

I realized, that `explorer.exe` is not loaded in task manager. I tried to execute `explorer.exe` manually, but no help.

I was googling and found, that I could try `sfc /scannow` in cmd (ran as administrator) and this is from my CBS.log:

```
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Idle processing thread terminated normally
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Trusted Installer is shutting down because: SHUTDOWN_REASON_AUTOSTOP
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    TiWorker signaled for shutdown, going to exit.
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Ending the TrustedInstaller main loop.
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Starting TrustedInstaller finalization.
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Ending TrustedInstaller finalization.
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Ending the TiWorker main loop.
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Starting TiWorker finalization.
2015-09-19 17:02:02, Info                  CBS    Ending TiWorker finalization.
```

I selected that by the time (when that scans stops), there is more, older information, but flagged as `CSI`. I don't know if you need it, if yes, I will upload file somewhere.

Comment: those are no error messages. share the complete **CBS.log**

Comment: Here it is: http://www.filedropper.com/cbs_2 I omitted other logs, only logs from 19.9. remain.

Comment: migwiz.lnk and rasctrnm.h can't be repaired. Run DISM instead, it can download corrupted files: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: does it now work?

Comment: There was a problem with folder system32's permissions. I repaired it with NPT.

Comment: what is NPT? Post an answer what you did

Comment: NPT is NTFS Permissions Tools (http://dbcstudio.net/software/npt/main.html). I clicked in the top left left "File -> Add folder" and selected "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\", then same action, but added folder "system32". Now, right click on SysWOW64, select "Copy security settings", then right click on system32 and select "Paste security settings" - that's all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to download NTP program (NTFS Permissions Tools from http://dbcstudio.net/software/npt/main.html) and then do these steps:

1. From "File -> Add folder" select any folder from "C:\Windows\", ie. "SysWOW64" (there are good permissions)
2. Now repeat last action, but select problem folder, for me it was "System32"
3. On folder "SysteWOW64" press right mouse click and select "Copy security settings", then press right mouse click on folder "System32" and select "Paste security settings"
4. That's all, now just restart computer